# The Edge Set Grown in Kruskal's Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm

Let G = (V, E) be a weighted, connected and undirected graph. Let T be the edge set that is grown in Kruskal's algorithm and stopped after k iterations (so T might contain less than |E|-1 edges). Let W(T) be the weighted sum of this set.
Let T’ be an acylic edge set such that |T| = |T’|. Prove that W(T) <= W(T’)

I understand the original proof of the algorithm and I’ve tried several approaches to tackle this, neither worked.

For example: I thought an induction on |T| might work.
For |T| = 1 it’s obvious.

We assume correctness for |T|=k and prove (or not…) for k+1.  Assume by contradiction that there exists an edge set T’ such that |T’|=k+1 and W(T’) < W(T).

Let e be the last edge added by Kruskal algorithm. So for any edge f in T’, W(f) < W(e) (otherwise we remove the edges from the 2 sets and get a contradiction).

This can only happen if every edge in T’ is already in T or forms a cycle with T – {e}.

…

Note: It's not the same proof as in Kruskal's algorithm. We don't even know whether T' is connected.

I have no idea what to do next. I would really appreciate any help,
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Let `T’` be an edge set such that `|T| = |T’|`. Prove that `W(T) <= W(T’)`.

You'll have a hard time doing that, since it's false in general.

Consider

```
   1
 A---B
2 \ / 3
   C
   | 4
   D
```

Kruskal's algorithm produces the edge set `T = { (A,B), (A,C), (C,D) }`, which is the unique minimal spanning tree.

But the edge set `T' = { (A,B), (A,C), (B,C) }` has the same cardinality as `T`, and

```
W(T') = 6 < W(T) = 7
```

There's some condition missing in the problem statement (like that `T'` should connect the graph).

---

> You're right. I forgot to mention that there is no cycle in `T'`

In that case, `T'` spans a tree<sup>(1)</sup>. And since `|T'| = |T|` is assumed, the tree that `T'` spans connects the graph, i.e. is a spanning tree.

<sup>(1)</sup> From the absence of cycles, it follows directly that each connected component of `T'` is a tree. A tree with `n` vertices has `n-1` edges. Thus if `T'` has `k` connected components, the number of vertices in the graph is

```
V = |T'| + k
```

But `T` is a spanning tree, and `|T| = |T'|`, hence

```
V = |T| + 1 = |T'| + 1
```

which implies `k = 1`.

Thus you are asked to simply prove the correctness of Kruskal's algorithm. You can find proofs in the literature easily, for example [on wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal%27s_algorithm#Proof_of_correctness).

A proof of correctness (by induction on the number of vertices):

Lemma: Let `G` be a connected graph with `N > 1` vertices, and `T` a minimal spanning tree of `G`. Let `e` be an edge in `T`.
Then `T \ {e}` projects to a minimal spanning tree of the graph `G'` obtained from `G` by identifying the two endpoints `a` and `b` of `e`. Conversely, if `T'` is a set of edges of `G` that projects to a minimal spanning tree of `G'`, then `T' ∪ {e}` is a minimal spanning tree of `G`.

Proof: Let `p : G -> G'` be the projection identifying `a` and `b`.

Then `p(T \ {e})` has no cycles.

Suppose `p(T \ {e})` contained a cycle `C`. Then `p^(-1)(C)` must be a path connecting `a` and `b`. But then `T` would contain the cycle `p^(-1)(C) ∪ {e}`, contradicting the premise that `T` is a tree.

Thus `p(T \ {e})` is a cycle-free set of edges of `G'` with cardinality `N - 2`, and that implies (see above) that it is a spanning tree.

Let `T''` be a minimal spanning tree of `G'` and `S = p^(-1)(T'')`.

Then `S ∪ {e}` has no cycles.

If there were a cycle in `S`, that would project to a cycle in `T''`, so every cycle in `S ∪ {e}` must contain `e`. Suppose `C` were a cycle in `S ∪ {e}`. Then `C \ {e}` is a path connecting `a` and `b`, thus `C \ {e}` projects to a cycle in `G'`, since `a` and `b` project to the same vertex of `G'`. That contradicts the premise that `T''` is a tree.

So `S ∪ {e}` is an edge set of cardinality `N - 1` without cycles, and hence (see above) a spanning tree of `G`.

Then `W(T) <= W(S ∪ {e})` since `T` is a minimal spanning tree, and thus

```
W(p(T \ {e})) = W(T \ {e}) <= W(S) = W(T'')
```

Since `T''` is assumed to be a minimal spanning tree of `G'`, it follows that equality holds, and that `p(T \ {e})` is a minimal spanning tree of `G'`, and that `S ∪ {e}` is a minimal spanning tree of `G`.

Now to the induction to prove the correctness of Kruskal's algorithm:

For a graph with at most two vertices, it is obvious that the algorithm produces a minimal spanning tree.

For `n >= 2`, assume the correctness of the algorithm for all connected graphs with at most `n` vertices. (Induction hypothesis)

Let `G` be a connected graph with `n+1` vertices. Let `e` be the first edge chosen in the algorithm, and `a` and `b` its endpoints.

Let `G'` be the graph obtained from `G` by identifying `a` and `b`, and `p :: G -> G'` the projection.

Let `T` be the edge set selected by the algorithm.

Then `p(T \ {e})` is the edge set selected by Kruskal's algorithm on `G'`. Thus, by the Lemma above, `T` is a minimal spanning tree of `G`.

(Okay, probably the proof in wikipedia is simpler, but I wanted to produce a different one.)

Comment: Thanks! you're right. I forgot to mention that there is no cycle in T'

Comment: Updated. Is there any point of porting a proof of correctness here?

Comment: Yeah, I still have no idea how to prove it ...

Comment: Please note that we don't know whether T' is connected

Comment: Sorry for being unclear

Comment: @Robert777 It follows from `|T'| = |T|` and the absence of cycles that `T'` is connected. Since there are no cycles, each connected component of `T'` is a tree. Let the components be `C_1, ..., C_k` with `E_1, ..., E_k` edges. Then `C_i` has `E_i + 1` vertices, since it's a tree. Thus the graph has `|T'| + k` vertices. But, since `T` is a spanning tree, it has `|T| + 1` vertices, whence `k = 1`.

Comment: @Robert777 Added a proof. But maybe the one on wikipedia is simpler to follow.

Comment: Wow, thanks! I can't believe you've written all this just for me. Thanks :)

Comment: @Robert777 Not only for you. Also for me (it's fun to think up a new proof), and future visitors that might learn from it.